# Conditional correlation in Farlie–Gumbel–Morgenstern distribution

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability, copula

I am constructing a bi-variate  Farlie–Gumbel–Morgenstern distribution with normal and exponential marginals. I was able to find conditional mean and conditional variance with the help of references. However, I was not able to find any help in finding conditional correlation. Is this question conceptually wrong? If not, please help me by sharing whatever you know or have that might help me to find conditional correlation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "conditional correlation" but the correlation coefficient of the bivariate distribution can be found using *Mathematica*:

```
dist = CopulaDistribution[{"FGM",alpha}, {NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], 
   ExponentialDistribution[lambda]}]
cov = Covariance[dist]
cor = cov[[1, 2]]/(sigma/lambda)
```

results in the correlation coefficient `cor = alpha/(2 Sqrt[Pi])`.